# Printing a txt file inside python shell

Tags: python, shell

I have an assignment for class that has me transfer txt data from excel and execute in python. But every time I run it, only hex is displayed. I was wondering how to have the data displayed in ascii in the shell. This is the code I have so far. Is it possible to print it out in ascii in the shell?

```
infile = open("data.txt", 'r')
listName = [line.rstrip() for line in infile]
print (listName)
infile.close()
```

Comment: So what's your question? doesn't this code work?

Comment: ...are you using windows?

Comment: You said you're transferring text data from Excel. Is `data.txt` an actual text file, or is it an Excel workbook that has simply been renamed?

Comment: You'll need to write or find and use a module that can read and convert Excel files into a form that Python understands. There are many of the latter — free and commercial — out there if you look around.

Comment: It is an actual file. I am not currently using windows but it displays the same on my Mac and my PC desktop. ANd yes technically the code works but it displays the txt data in hex. And part of the assignment is printing it to read the data in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

The reason its not working is because you are opening an Excel file - which is in a special format and is not a plain text file.

You can test this by yourself by opening the file in a text editor like Notepad; and you'll see the contents aren't in text.

To open the file and read its contents in Python you will need to do one of these two things:

1. Open the file in Excel, then save it as a text file (or a comma separated file CSV). Keep in mind if you do this, then you can only save one sheet at a time.
2. Use a module like [`pyexcel`](https://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which will allow you to read the Excel file correctly in Python.

Just opening the file as plain text (or changing its extension) doesn't convert it.